# Javascript: Replace all P tags with Div (without any library)

Tags: javascript

Below is a code snippet

```
var pTags=document.getElementsByTagName('p');
for(i=0;i<pTags.length;i++)
{
    var p=pTags[i],  div=document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML='P tag replaced with a div tag';
    p.parentNode.replaceChild(div, p);
}
```

It should replace all `P` tags with `Div` but it's not replacing all but some of them. The `red` ones ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eZNqn/)) are not replacing.

I don't need this but I want to know what is I'm doing wrong here ? So, my question is why not it's working in this way. Hope someone can tell me the fact.

Thanks for your effort!

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606547/why-does-replacechild-behave-oddly-when-replacing-one-kind-of-element-with-ano

Comment: @Garett, Thanks but I didn't see it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` returns a live node list so every time you replace a node the list changes, so you only want to get the first node in the list and replace it until the list is empty, see http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/eZNqn/4/

Comment: Oh ! Thanks a lot, everyday I learn something new from So. Thanks again for your quick and brilliant answer.

Answer (score 6):

The one line way ;-)

First, select any elem you want (in this case, all content of body)

```
var elem = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
var target = elem.innerHTML;
```

The "line"

```
elem.innerHTML = target.replace(/(<div)/igm, '<p').replace(/<\/div>/igm, '</p>');
```

I hope that helps. [See in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/mcurbelop/znX2v/2/)